# Build array to feed to Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with 2D arrays with the shape (1542, 2):

```
[[-0.83776179 -1.        ]
 [-0.83229744 -0.99845917]
 [-0.81120124 -0.99691834]
 ...
 [ 0.33190834  0.99691834]
 [ 0.3312287   0.99845917]
 [ 0.34686055  1.        ]]
```

With this array, I need to group them so that for each entry, i have the 200 entries before, as I want to predict the next entrie using the 200 ones before,
in this way:

```
[[[-0.83776179 -1.        ]
 [-0.83229744 -0.99845917]
 [-0.81120124 -0.99691834]
 ...200 elements
 [ 0.33190834  0.99691834]
 [ 0.3312287   0.99845917]
 [ 0.34686055  1.        ]]
[[-0.83776179 -1.        ]
 [-0.83229744 -0.99845917]
 [-0.81120124 -0.99691834]
 ... 200 elements
 [ 0.33190834  0.99691834]
 [ 0.3312287   0.99845917]
 [ 0.34686055  1.        ]]]
```

What would be the best way using numpy?

Comment: Not sure, but seems that you need just put your array inside other array. `new_array=[your_array]`. Also you can try to reshape the array.

Comment: It seems to me you want sliding windows over a time series? [timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want you want is select the 200 features before each element, for the elements of index 200 to 1541:

With `X` the original data

```
X_2 = np.array([X[i-200: i] for i in range(200, len(X))])
```

Thus `print(X_2)` outputs `(1342, 200, 2)`
Each element of `X_2` is a pack of 200 features to predict the next one. Because we began at index 200 (to get 200 elements before), we only have 1342 resulting elements.

**Note** that this takes up a lot of useless memory as you copy overlapping values of the original array into each entry of the new one.